# Bootstrap 4 Wordpress - tooltips not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tooltip

I have a wordpress site with the Bootstrap 4 theme installed. I am working on a child theme.

The theme comes with jquery including popper.js, so all javascript should be in place.

I have tried adding this in my :

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

And setting the property on my elements. Will not work.

I have tried setting this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tooltip-test').tooltip();
</script>

<a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a>
```

Will not work. It is on my site https://www.casinoguide.dk/ - and I can not figure out if anything is missing in my javascripts included.

I am working on my localhost and with the second attempt I receive the following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Best regards
Rasmus

Comment: Are you sure the jquery is there? What line this error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the more verbose `jQuery(...)` syntax instead:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

This happens because different plugins may already use the `$` character, so jQuery has a *no conflict* call to make sure it doesn't break other stuff inadvertently. Check out the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) documentation for more information. This shows a nice workaround where you can still use `$`, as long as it's in a function.

Seeing as you usually want your code to only run when jQuery is ready, you might as well do it in the `ready()` function. So your code above could be changed to:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

As long as your jQuery code is inside the function above, you are fine to keep using `$`.